# Python: Writing Nested Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to write a nested dictionary to a .csv file. Here is is a simple example:

```
import csv
import itertools

fields = [ 'org', '2015', '2014', '2013' ]
dw     = { 'orgname1': { '2015' : 2, '2014' : 1, '2013' : 1 },
           'orgname2': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 2, '2013' : 3 },
           'orgname3': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 3, '2013' : 1 }
        }

with open("test_output.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.writer( f )
    years = dw.values()[0].keys()
    for key in dw.keys():
        w.writerow([key, [dw[key][year] for year in years]])
```

This gets me a table with two columns: the first contains `orgname`; the second contains [2, 1, 1] (or the corresponding values from the sub-dictionary). I'd like a table with four columns: one for `orgname` and then three for the corresponding list elements.

Comment: dicts don't have order so you are in trouble straight away

Comment: @PadraicCunningham agreed. However, his keys seem to follow a lexographic order. So, he could still make it work by sorting dw.keys() and then iterating over that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
w.writerow([key, [dw[key][year] for year in years]])
```

To:

```
w.writerow([key] + [dw[key][year] for year in years])
```

Otherwise, you try to write something like `[orgname1, [2, 1, 1]]` to the csv, while you mean `[orgname1, 2, 1, 1]`.

As Padraic mentioned, you may want to change `years = dw.values()[0].keys()` to `years = sorted(dw.values()[0].keys())` or `years = fields[1:]` to avoid random behaviour.

Comment: it is not necessary to sort years, if you would be using DictWriter as suggested in other Answers

Comment: @hexereisoftware Yeah, but that would just be copying now.

Answer (score 24):

This looks like a job for [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv
import itertools
import sys

fields = [ 'org', '2015', '2014', '2013' ]
dw     = { 'orgname1': { '2015' : 2, '2014' : 1, '2013' : 1 },
           'orgname2': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 2, '2013' : 3 },
           'orgname3': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 3, '2013' : 1 }
        }

w = csv.DictWriter( sys.stdout, fields )
for key,val in sorted(dw.items()):
    row = {'org': key}
    row.update(val)
    w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: you deserve the best comment actually, because you where the first complete solution and i like the way you used the the dicts update function. i adapted that in my answer in a separate function to keep it a one liner afterwards. so my answer is pretty much yours, changed to file output and added headers :)

Answer (score 14):

Alternative implementation using [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and with headers

```
import csv
import itertools

fields = [ 'org', '2015', '2014', '2013' ]
dw     = { 'orgname1': { '2015' : 2, '2014' : 1, '2013' : 1 },
           'orgname2': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 2, '2013' : 3 },
           'orgname3': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 3, '2013' : 1 }
        }

with open("test_output.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
    w.writeheader()
    for k in dw:
        w.writerow({field: dw[k].get(field) or k for field in fields})
```

Output:

```
org,2015,2014,2013
orgname1,2,1,1
orgname3,1,3,1
orgname2,1,2,3
```

Comment: i like your answer best, straight forward :) you could consider sorting `dw` by its keys since in your output the order of the orgnames has changed from input. using `sorted(dw.items())`  fixes this

Comment: Dear Python 3 users who don't want to embarrass themselves spending hours on this like I just did when all you have to do is simply switch `open("test_output.csv", "wb")` for `open("test_output.csv", "w", newline='')` and the above solution will work flawlessly. You'll get a `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file' ` otherwise. Don't be a nana and try to encode your whole dictionary into `ascii` like me.

Comment: If my value of any key is 0 then I got key as value like orgname1,orgname1,1,1 if 2015: 0 is for orgname1. So any solution for this. @Łukasz Rogalski

Answer (score 3):

Using DictWriter there is no need in sorting the fields in advance, since `w.writerow()` will assure the correct order. But it does make sense to sort the items themselves.

So putting together all the above suggestions and picking the best of each, i would come up with following code:

```
import csv
import itertools

def mergedict(a,b):
    a.update(b)
    return a

fields = [ 'org', '2015', '2014', '2013' ]
dw     = { 'orgname1': { '2015' : 2, '2014' : 1, '2013' : 1 },
           'orgname2': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 2, '2013' : 3 },
           'orgname3': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 3, '2013' : 1 }
        }

with open("test_output.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter( f, fields )
    w.writeheader()
    for k,d in sorted(dw.items()):
        w.writerow(mergedict({'org': k},d))
```

i added a tiny `mergedict()` function that makes it a one liner further down.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be an easier way:

```
import csv

fields = [ 'org', '2015', '2014', '2013' ]
dw     = { 'orgname1': { '2015' : 2, '2014' : 1, '2013' : 1 },
           'orgname2': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 2, '2013' : 3 },
           'orgname3': { '2015' : 1, '2014' : 3, '2013' : 1 }
        }

with open("test_output.csv", "w") as csv_file:
  csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
  csvwriter.writerow(['org', '2015', '2014', '2013'])

  for org in dw:
     csvwriter.writerow(org, dw[org]['2015'], dw[org]['2014'], dw[org]['2013'])
```

Comment: Missing parentheses in the last line to make it work